# Не работает success в Ajax

Tags: ajax

Есть скрипт отправки данных с формы на почтовый ящик через ajax.
Сам скрипт работает, данные на почту доходят, но не появляется никаких уведомлений об успешной отправке данных.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как изменить код, чтобы после отправки данных, пользователю сообщалось, что данные отправлены?

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $("#form").submit(function() { 
            var form_data = $(this).serialize();
            $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "send.php", 
            data: form_data,
            success: function(response) {
              alert("Данные отправлены");
              document.getElementById(form-result).innerHTML = "Запрос отправлен";
            },
            error: function(response) {
              document.getElementById(form-result).innerHTML = "Ошибка при отправке формы";
                }
            })
    })
  })
</script>
```

Comment: А в панели разработчика (F12) в мониторинге сети какой ответ присылает сервер? И есть ли что в js-консоли?

Comment: А ещё, я так понимаю, вместо `document.getElementById(form-result)` должно быть `document.getElementById("form-result")`

Comment: у него походу неправильно указан dataType и из-за этого приходит ошибка

Comment: В консоли ничего, кавычки поставил (странно, раньше этой строчки в принципе не было и все равно не работало) : alert срабатывает, но сообщение в диве#form-result не появляется

Comment: А почему делают запросы через `form` именно?

Comment: Хм, если alert срабатывает — то `form-result` на странице вообще точно отображается?) Вдруг где-нибудь завалялось `display: none`, перекрылось элементом или ещё что-нибудь; проверьте через веб-инспектор (всё тот же F12)

Comment: Отображается нормально, если сам вписываю текст в этот див непосредственно через html, то все видно как надо. Запрос через form, потому что сам в jquery не силен, собрал скрипт на основе примеров из гугла

Answer (score 3, accepted):

У Вас по `submit`у формы перезагружается страница. Чтобы этого не происходило - добавьте `return false;` в обработчик `submit`:

```
$("#form").submit(function() { 
  var form_data = $(this).serialize();
  $.ajax({
    ...
  });
  return false;
});
```

*Update*

Имеет место "race condition". На сервер отправляются два запроса - ajax и submit формы. Порядок возвращения ответов на запросы - произвольный. Если первым приходит ответ на submit - страница перезагружается, и обрабатывать success от ajax'а - нечему. Если первым приходит ответ на ajax, показывается alert, a тем временем приходит ответ на submit - после нажатия на OK alert'а, страница перезагружается и изменения html исчезают.

Comment: А как тогда работает alert?

Comment: @andreymal - Он не работает.

Comment: а комментарии утверждают, что работает

Comment: а как сделать, чтобы не перезагружалась?

Comment: @Руслан Посмотрите внимательно на код в ответе.

Comment: вы про return false? добавил в код, все равно уведомлений об отправке нет

Comment: @andreymal Ну это просто. Имеет место "race condition". На сервер отправляются два запроса - ajax и submit формы. Порядок возвращения ответов на запросы - произвольный. Если первым приходит ответ на submit - страница перезагружается, и обрабатывать success от ajax'а - нечему. Если первым приходит ответ на ajax, показывается alert, a тем временем приходит ответ на submit - после нажатия на OK alert'а, страница перезагружается и изменения html исчезают.

Comment: @Руслан - Вы неправильно воспроизвели мой код у себя.

Comment: Точно! Заработало! И alert и div с результатом) Спасибо большое)